# Doing diff in Moment.js, today equals today and tomorrow, returning -0. Why?

Tags: javascript, compare, momentjs, days

I want to check if a certain date is today, so I do:

```
var a = moment();
var b = moment([2016, 5, 20]);
a.diff(b, 'days')
```

And I get `o`, but when I do `var b = moment([2016, 5, 21]);`, which is tomorrow I get `-0` which I have no idea what it means, and for Javascript it is still `0` or false for any kind of comparison.

How do I get it right?

Comment: Negative zero is used in many programming languages when a number underflows to zero. In JavaScript it can pretty much be thought of as the same as zero in most use cases. Because it does look ugly for display, what you are seeing here was recently changed in moment and will return 0 in the next release (2.14), which should be out in the next couple weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`isSame()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/):

```
var a = moment()
var b = moment([2016, 5, 21]);    // it's already Jun 21st for me
var isToday = a.isSame(b, 'day'); // true
```